# TypeError list indices must be integers

Tags: python

I have recently started to learn python. The following code is throwing type error stating that I can't use tuples as index in a list. I am quite sure I am using integers and not list to access to access my list. The error is thrown at the line where I build a sub-matrix. Can you help me out?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "matrix_input.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(contains(matrix, target))
   File "matrix_input.py", line 33, in contains
    sub_matrix = [row[index:len(target[0])] for row in matrix[i, len(target)]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

This  is the function throwing the error:

```
def sub_array(row, sub_row):
  i = 0
  index = -1
  for idx, val in enumerate(row):
    if i >= len(sub_row):
      break
    elif val == sub_row[i]:
      index = idx
      i+=1
    else:
      i = 0

  return index if i == len(sub_row) else -1

def contains(matrix, target):

  for i in range(len(matrix)):
    index = sub_array(matrix[i], target[0])
    if index is not -1:
      sub_matrix = [row[index:len(target[0])] for row in matrix[i, len(target)]]
      print(sub_matrix)
      if sub_matrix == target:
        return "YES"

  return "NO"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix[i, len(target)]` attempts to access an item in `matrix` with the tuple `i, len(target)` as an index – not an integer. It appears you intended to use `matrix[i][len(target)]` instead.

You should compare integers with `==`/`!=`, too – `index != -1` instead of `index is not -1`.

Comment: I replace the coma with : and it worked. Thank you. What's the difference between `is not` and `!=`?

Comment: As a side note, that sort of array[y, x] notation is perfectly acceptable for numpy arrays.  So there will be code examples out there where that notation is used correctly.  Just a wild guess, but that might have caused the OP's confusion.   Regarding OP's second question about "is" and equality... that is too complicated for a short answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: @GiuseppePes `is` tests identity `==` tests value. It's possible there is more than one object representing `-1` (although unlikely), so the value could be `-1` but the identity will be a different object.